# Another ring of integers in a cubic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I've been trying to tackle the following problem:

Let $\alpha$ denote a root of $p = x^3 - x - 4$ and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Find the ring of integers of $K$, and show that $K$ has class number $1$.

I already proved that $\{1, \alpha, (\alpha + \alpha^2)/2\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis; however, I do not know how to show that the ring of integers of $K$ is precisely $\mathbb{Z}[(\alpha + \alpha^2)/2]$. It is clear that $\mathbb{Z}[(\alpha + \alpha^2)/2]$ is a subring of the ring of integers, but why is the whole thing, i.e., how can we generate $\alpha$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $(\alpha + \alpha^2)/2$ and its different powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\beta=\frac12(\alpha+\alpha^2)$. Then
$$\beta^2=\frac{\alpha^2+2\alpha^3+\alpha^4}4
=\frac{\alpha^2+(2+\alpha)(4+\alpha)}4
=2+\frac{3\alpha+\alpha^2}2=2+\alpha+\beta$$
so
$$\alpha=\beta^2-\beta-2.$$